# Selectively changing only one of multiple HTML background image sizes with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm writing a website that uses multiple images for its background as follows,

```
background-image:
   url('someimage1.png'),
   url('image2.png'),
   url('image3.png');
```

And I can change certain CSS style properties of each image in one statement like so,

```
background-size:
   5vw auto,      // styles image 1
   100% 99%,      // then image 2
   auto 98vh;     // and 3
```

Is it possible for me to, for example, change the `background-size` property of the third background image without in any way changing the that of the first and second? I'd like to be able to change one of the image's sizes in a 'responsive' way, but for the other two to stay the same size regardless.

Preferably I'd be able to achieve this without using javascript.

Comment: it can be done with js or jquery. If you need help, post your html and css

Comment: Unfortunately it's for a squarespace website so that'll be a bit of a task. It allows for 'injection' of CSS, which I'm doing to provide custom styling. A new background sizing is applied when the screen size becomes less than 1200px wide, detected using the @media tag - that's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: mmmmm, can i see a live example of the site?

Comment: If browser compatibility using the CSS variables as in Temani's answer isn't good enough for you (IE 11 doesn't support them yet, https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), then maybe (if the surrounding layout allows for it) a ::before and :after pseudo element, positioned absolute to cover the whole width and height of the parent, could hold one of the three background images each - that would allow you to selectively change only one at a time as well.

Comment: @CBroe i also though about this solution but it would be tricky if we have to change the middle one of the backgrounds and/or if there is more than 3.

Comment: _"but it would be tricky if we have to change the middle one"_ - why, you can target `element`, `element::before` and `element:after` individually at any time, and which is the middle one is just a matter of stacking order on the z axis. _"or if there is more than 3"_ - sure, obviously. Although I might suspect that on a squarespace page there might be a certain level of nested elements available, so that the principle could possibly extended to more ...

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO the site's not in a 'live'able state at the moment lol, sorry, I appreciate the effort anyway.

And thanks all for the responses, I'll have to look into what '::before' and ':after' do exactly, I'm a bit of a web noob (hence squarespace!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables and easily update them with media query or custom classes:

```css
:root {
  --size-one: 100% 50%;
  --size-two: 50% 100%;
  --size-three: 80% 100%;
}

.back {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red), linear-gradient(black, blue), linear-gradient(30deg, black, green);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--size-one), var(--size-two), var(--size-three);
}

.update {
  --size-three: 80% 80%;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  :root {
    --size-one: 80% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back update">
</div>
```

Comment: This did achieve what I was after, although the support of CSS variable worries me a bit - I'll have to look into further ways around this. Thanks!